# Difference between URI and bitmap image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, uri

What is the best practice to display an image to `imageView`? We have two type of image, one is `bitmap` and another is `URI`. If I use bitmap,

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

the image is a bit blurry.

If  I use `URI`, sometimes I get out of memory issues.

```
 URI imageUri = data.getData();
 imageView.setImageURI(imageURI);
```

What is the difference between the two ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageView has 4 APIs to specify the image.

1. setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)
2. setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
3. setImageResource(int resId)
4. setImageURI(URI uri)

here `setImageDrawable` is the primitive function other APIs rely on. The other 3 are just helper methods making you write less code.

`setImageURI`, `setImageBitmap` both  run on the UI thread. I would say `setImageBitmap` is bit faster than the first one. `setImageURI` really depends where the Uri resource comes from (e.g. the uri could point to a remote file not even stored on the phone).

`setImageURI`() is not better to use as reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup.

Better to use the following:-

`setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)` or `setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)` and `BitmapFactory` instead.

you can also return `bitmap` from `uri` and use it in `imageview`

```
 Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
Imageview my_img_view = (Imageview ) findViewById (R.id.my_img_view);
my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Also sometime loading large bitmap on imageview can cause out of memory exception..so you should load bitmap efficiently..

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

mImageView.setImageBitmap(
    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));
```

see those link also..for better understanding

1. [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)
2. Android developer documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: How do I know what is the value for reqWidth and reqHeight so the image will not look blurry ?

Answer (score 3):

`Bitmap` is a ready image (`set of bytes with color data`) and `URI` is a path to something. `URI` can be `/emulated/home/...` , can be http://google.com and so on.